# WiFi calling +4g via tP link mobile wifi

Tags: virtual-wifi

I am going on holiday to North Wales, my mobile phone provider has no coverage so no wi fi either.  If I get WiFi calling + 4g package from my provider can I make phone calls from somewhere like the top of a Welsh mountain or similar where there is no WiFi or mobile coverage. I would like to make calls in an emergency or use maps etc.
Do I have to buy another sim for the mobile WiFi unit?
Thank you.

Comment: If you go somewhere where there is no cell coverage (at all), you won’t be able to make calls or access the internet no matter what you do. Keep in mind that emergency calls already make use of any network, not just yours. Satellite phones are an option but extremely expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Your current provider may provide a "Roaming" feature where you use the service that is available where you are and costs are billed back to your current provider.

Your provider charges you a Roaming fee to cover these costs (and to make more profit).

The other alternative is to get a SIM card that comes with a provider  (ISP) as part of the SIM card. You can get prepaid SIM cards for a day, several days and so on. It is your responsibility to change the SIM cards.

My own ISP offers a barely acceptable rate (cost) for Roaming and I use my ISP Roaming for travel on my own continent and travel overseas.

So you have to choose the route you would go.